# What should be the better layout of hardwood floor on my hallway?

Tags: hardwood-floor

[image]

See the above picture, it looks to me to decide layout of bedroom A,B,C and play room is pretty straight forward.

But I do not have any idea what is the better layout on the hallway should be?

I am also thinking if I should change direction in Bedroom A to avoid too much expansion at vertical direction.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What type of flooring are you using? Is it prefinished, floating, laminate, glued,nailed down?

Comment: Get comfortable with cutting angles and put it all in at angles to the walls, remembering that you can use the offcuts from one side to fillout the other side, assuming your walls are parallel. Change angles at the thresholds of the doors.

Comment: @mikes, prefinished hardwood, nailed down

Comment: Are you planning on transition strips at room boundaries?  Is your floor flat and level enough to go transition free?  I'd probably go parallel with the longer walls of the hall breaking the hallway into 3 areas.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger, Thanks! Yes, I am going to put transition strips under the door for each room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is hardwood, then you could do something like the image attached. Have a transition board between two separate sections of the floor. There are different locations you can place the transition board, the position shown is just what I happen to like. Others may like the path leading from the door to Bedroom C, going from the corner of the stairs to the left of the Bedroom C room, or some other configuration. Overall, I feel transitioning with diagonal cuts - unfortunately, make give you best looking results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would divide the hallways into 3 areas and keep the areas approximately the same size.  Put the direction of the wood with the longest wall to keep cuts to a minimum.  In my mind this has the middle hallway start (reading left to right) with the angle change and end at the far side of bedroom C.

The change in direction from the hallway to the room would be transitioned at the door ways to make it as inconspicuous as possible.

Bedroom A should be fine.  The hardwood manufacturers typically specify the maximum dimensions and that room doesn't look like it would exceed the standard recommendation but check the install specifications.